# Big O notation for a sub linear algorithm

Tags: complexity, big-o

I have a function for which the complexity raise by the square ten of the exponent of the number.

Ex:

```
+-----+----------+
|Input|Complexity|
+-----+----------+
|0    |     1    |
|10   |     2    |
|100  |     3    |
|123  |     3    |
|1001 |     4    |
|9999 |     4    |
|10000|     5    |
|99999|     5    |
+-----+----------+
```

How to express its complexity in big O notation ?

Comment: ...and not nearly enough information to perform a real Big-Oh analysis.

Comment: I started editing the question to fix the grammar when I realized that the question would answer itself. Hint: if you define the relationship between "Input" and "Complexity" you will come up with the most likely answer, although the proof will be an analysis of the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical function that is like that is `log n`.  So the big O notation would be O(log n).

Comment: Log(n) is indeed very very close to the expected result, but slightly above. 
When giving a Big O notation, is it expected to be a (pretty accurate) approximation ?